# LNK4099 errors for many individual object files, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors

When building a large C++/Fortran app, I recently started getting LNK4099 errors for virtually every C++ object file. For example

```
Cfile.obj : warning LNK4099: PDB 'lnk{3FE844DB-7378-4485-9D93-6B1B48386536}.tmp' was not found with 'Cfile.obj' or at 'C:MyApp\x64\Debug\lnk{3FE844DB-7378-4485-9D93-6B1B48386536}.tmp'; linking object as if no debug info
```

Unlike a number of previous posts, this is not due to a library missing PDB info; the files with the errors are all my own source code, and freshly built.

This is Visual Studio 2015, building under 64-bit Windows 7. The problem occurs for both debug and release builds. The options for the debug build are C++: /Zi / Od; Linker: /DEBUG, Generate Full Program Database File.

The app is C++, using a Fortran library, created by Intel Fortran XE2017, and built with /debug:full. Linking to the Microsoft libraries (MFC, msimg32.lib, nafxcwd.lib, libcmtd.lib, etc) is static.

If I compile a single C++ source file AFile.cpp using F7 (Build/Compile) and then build the project, I get all the same errors EXCEPT there is none for AFile.obj. The debugging information for AFile is in the app's PDB (I can set breakpoints). Files that have the errors are missing debug info in the app's PDB (as the error message says), and I cannot set breakpoints.

What setting or configuration could be causing this mysterious behavior? I do not have this issue with smaller projects.

Comment: How much RAM do you have, and are you letting Windows set the swap file size?  How much disk space?  That's just something to check, I've had (different) linker failures trying to build Chromium with just 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: 32 GB RAM, 2.9 TB free disk. Windows sets the swap file size.

Answer (score 1):

The [LNK4099 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4099) shows a DUMPBIN command that can be used to list the full path name of a .pdb file associated with an object file...

> dumpbin /section:.debug$T /rawdata objectname.obj

It might be interesting to examine AFile.obj from your F7 experiment and another .obj file generated by the project build to see how the PDB file names differ (if they differ).

Assuming you're doing a build, not rebuild, of the project in your F7 experiment it might also be interesting to see what happens if you compile AFile.cpp with F7 and then do a full rebuild of the project.  A full rebuild would recompile AFile.cpp where a regular build wouldn't.

Once you know what you should be looking for you can start trying to figure out if your build is: **not** creating the PDB files; creating them in the wrong place; creating them with the wrong name; or removing them after they're created.

**UPDATE**

I should have added the caveat that [/PDBALTPATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbaltpath-use-alternate-pdb-path) can set the string shown by the DUMPBIN command above to a value different from the actual PDB file's pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Frank Boyne's suggestion, I found that

`dumpbin /section:.debug$T /rawdata *.obj`

lists the same result for all the object files, namely 0x1B byes of binary data, followed by the full path to App.pdb. Recompiling a single file shows the identical path, but slightly different binary data.

So, the answer is, the project's Program Database File Name property was set to `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb`, when it should have been `$(IntDir)%(Filename).pdb`. Following this change, .pdb files appeared with each object file (i e, separate file in the same directory), and the build completes without any LNK4099 errors.

This solves the original problem. I am wondering, though, if there is a way to have the PDB information added to a single output file, rather than producing a separate PDB file for each object file.